# Does the default Apache build not have PIE (position independent executable)?

Tags: security, apache2

I just built Apache from source, not something I usually do, and noticed that one of the build options was:

```
--enable-pie
```

This builds httpd as a Position Independent Executable which as I understand prevents ROP exploits. I would have expected this to be the default build, but normally when you see an "--enable" option in the build process, it means that the option is NOT enabled by default. Is this correct? PIE is not enabled in the default build of Apache2?